# What type of motor should I use in a conveyor and how should I design it?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, torque

I need to motorize the following conveyor :

[image]

It consists of 2 rolls and 9 round belts. The length L is 50 cm, the width l is 20 cm and the rolls have a radius r of 3 cm. Only the first roll will be motorized. The conveyor will be integrated into a bigger machine.

It is used to move one glass cup at a time from the beginning (A) to the end of the conveyor (B) in about 3 seconds. At the end the cup falls into a bin :

[image]

It is the first time I have to deal with motors. I have some questions :

- What type of motor should I use? I did some research and I think a DC motor might be enough : it is cheap and easy to drive, and the movement I have to implement is really simple. Am I right?
- In such a situation how do I compute the mechanical characteristics of the motor I need?
- As far as I understand, the motor would require a small speed and a not so small torque, so I might need a reductor. Is it right ?
  Are motors generally sold with reductors or is it a piece I need to buy separately?

Thank you for your support.

Comment: DC motor is a reasonable choice. They are available geared (in a wide range of ratios) for speed reduction or ungeared. Firm up your speed and torque requirements and get searching.

Comment: Is there a load change with speed on/off belt? does speed change matter? Is speed control needed? Will friction change? There are many types of DC motors, Series,shunt,compound and permanent magnet, brush and brushless. each with pros and cons for max power vs speed.  Gear or belt reduction is always an option. Do you need instant stop feature?

Comment: There are a lot of variables in any motor choice, depending on your method of control, simplicity/complexity, current range can be 100:1 from start torque to no load full speed, but choice simplified by your specs for inertia, acceleration limits, speed range , reliability and budget. Printers use a variety of motors and methods will give you some idea.

Comment: In the power range for this project, the only types of DC motor that you are likely to find are the permanent-magnet types either brushed or brushless. Part of the nature of brushless DC motors is that they require electronic control. Small brushed DC motors require voltage reduction and rectification to be powered by AC. Adding simple speed control to that would be inexpensive. The types of AC motors used in mechanical timers and microwave turntables and small fans may work, but starting torque could be a problem. The mechanical design dictates the motor specifications.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not just a single question and the answer requires the mechanical design details.